# How to add more custom states to intranet_workflow in Plone 4.1.4

Tags: python, workflow, plone, roles

How to add more custom states to intranet_workflow in Plone 4.1.4

I would like to add more approval levels. eg. approval

- role a : can only publish internally / retract to internal draft
- role b : can set the state to pending for review / retract
- role c : can  publish externally i.e finalize etc

How is it done? In short I would like to divide the states of intranet_workflow between different  custom roles.

Comment: go in zmi and look at portal_workflow. here more info: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-workflows-in-plone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yuri mentions, http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-workflows-in-plone is excellent documentation on workflows in general.  You may also find that http://plone.org/products/plone.app.workflowmanager is a useful graphical editor for workflows.  By design, it doesn't alter Plone's default workflows, but it will let you copy and edit them into a custom workflow.